# Schedule SMS, WhatsApp, and Facebook messages?

Tags: sms, whatsapp-messenger, facebook, automation

I would like to know if there is a way to schedule SMS, WhatsApp, and Facebook messages to be sent sometime in the future after composing them. Ideally, if some messages would have had to be sent while the device was powered off, I would like the message sending to be triggered automatically on start-up (configured to the particular app or service used to send the message).

I'm thinking of using an app to send respective intents to each app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

An app called [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/), for rooted phones can schedule SMS messages. According to its site, it can also be configured for Facebook Messenger, though I have not tried it.

Comment: Well, not sure if I can root my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo Android KitKat phone (wasn't even able to root the older SIII after it automatically updates its software). Besides, I've heard that if I do so then Google Wallet will stop working, is this true? I wonder whether there are any solutions which will not require rooting. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson Google Wallet works on rooted devices, it just displays a warning banner when you open it. I'm not sure that you actually need root in order to schedule an SMS in Tasker, either. It can use root for certain functions (like killing processes), but many work without it. Sending an SMS isn't something that should require root, since, for example, 3rd party messaging apps are capable of doing this. Sending messages in other apps (like Facebook) may require root, though.

Comment: Interesting about Google Wallet. As to sending messages, if the Facebook app is programmed to properly respond to the Android intent for sending messages, then this would work. Sending an intent doesn't require root. And an Android service can run in the background also without root. So I'm puzzled.

Comment: Actually this is false. There are support for third party apps and yes, given enough time you could create a Facebook API of your own where you could post messages via a HTTP POST relay.. But natively no, this app does not support the use of sending facebook messages.